# Looking for VSTS REST API to set the compare branch on a given repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, branch, repo

I am looking for help to find the REST API to set "compare" branch on Azure DevOps.

I have found one below API that is only modifying the default branch.
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{RepositoryID}?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7BRepositoryID%7D?api-version=6.0)

Could someone please help in finding the similar API for modifying the compare branch?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Kevin, No the API provided was not working. I have found other API below which was working fine for quite sometime and not working since yesterday. Patch https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_apis/Settings/Repository/{repository id}/Entries/me?api-version=4.1-preview.1

Answer (score 0):

To modify the compare branch, you can use the following Rest API:

API URL:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/Settings/Repository/{RepoID}/Entries/me?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "Branches.Compare":"refs/heads/branchname"
}
```